# mod_rewrite ignores existing files

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

There is a number of similar questions, but none of them help.
I have the following rule in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^images/.*$ - [F]
```

so for folders like /images/goods/ or /images/nonexistentfile.jpg I get 'Forbidden' which is what I want. The problem is if an existent file is requested, my rules are ignored and the file is served. In fact if I make a deliberate mistake in .htaccess I don't get an Internal Server Error as I would when requesting folders or non-existent files. What should I look for?

---

apache2.conf

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:8080>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/s3/data/www/domain.com
    SuexecUserGroup s3 s3
    CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/domain.com.access.log combin$
    ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/domain.com.error.log
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ServerAdmin example@domain.com
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/s3/data:.:/tmp"
    php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f example@domain.com
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/s3/data/mod-tmp"
    php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/s3/data/mod-tmp"
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</VirtualHost>
```

anything else I should post here?

Comment: Can you post all config?

Comment: This rule should work for existing files. (i) are there any other rules/cond in that file (ii) are there any rules defined in /images/.htaccess?

Comment: there are no .htaccess files anywhere in /images. And I carefully looked through config files and I swear I didn't find anything else that had to do with this site or mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case someone has the same problem, it is painfully trivial. The default ISPManager installation puts nginx in front of Apache for static files...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
I put the following .htaccess in to the images folder to forbid access to jpg files (in my case)

```
IndexIgnore */*
<Files ~ ".*\.jpg$">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: that wouldn't solve my problem because I will also need to do some dynamic watermarking with certain images, but I didn't mention it not to kindle anyone's anger with such a waste of resources

Comment: so if the image requested is existent a script process it applying a watermark to the image. Is it right?

Comment: yup, but for some reason .htaccess is completely ignored when a file exists

Comment: The docs for the F flag says that this behaviour is similar to deny istruction posted above. I make a check on my lamp server and seems to work with the following istructions RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^images/.*$ - [F]. Where is placed your .htaccess?

Comment: It works perfectly on other installations and on my local machine as well. It is this exact shaitan-server that gives me trouble, a default ISPmanager installation.

Comment: Could you post a page (phpinfo) or something that show the OS Version and Web Server Version?

Comment: Apache API Version 20051115

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're htaccess file isn't being applied. Try adding an [AllowOverride directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) in your vhost config:

```
<Directory "/var/www/s3/data/www/domain.com/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

By default, AllowOverride should be set to `All`, but it's possible your host set it to something else at the server config level.

Comment: nah, it is AllowOverride All.